# How weird, bizarre and surreal would a post singularity world appear from the view of an average person?

Tags: science-fiction, singularity

If AI get so smart and computers become so powerful that technologies that weren't dreamed even in sci fi become possible and part of everyday life and new kind of materials with surreal looks and properties come to existence and the creation of new kinds of sentience, how surreal the world is gonna be in the future?Will it be somewhat creepy as well?

How would a person interact with everyday things if they cannot even understand the most basic technologies?

Comment: How would we know? You are the author, you tell us

Comment: Wait, you’re asking us to imagine unimaginable technology? I think the only decent answer would be “very”.

Comment: *"How would a person interact with everyday things if they cannot even understand the most basic technologies?"* It's all about the user friendliness of the UI. In the real world lots of people do not understand basic guidelines about POB, yet they keep posting POB material just fine, so...

Comment: *"How surreal the world is gonna be in the future?"* For its inhabitants, not at all surreal; familiarity breeds contempt. For the reader, who does not live in that world? Very surreal. *"Will it be somewhat creepy as well?"* If you want it to be creepy it will be creeepy. *"How would a person interact with everyday things if they cannot even understand the most basic technologies?"* They would interact very well, thank you. Are you *certain* that you understand how come I can type a text over here and you can read it over there, across thousands of miles?

Comment: How many people today understand even the most basic stuff about how their stuff works? I mean a microwave is already the limit, isn't it? And still people use things completely out if their understanding successfully

Comment: To add to what Radotz_35 said: flat-earthers use Google Maps and Waze, which rely on GPS. Think of that.

Answer (score 2):

### Possible answer: not weird at all.

Maybe it's my imagination that has its own limits, but I don't think the world would look *that* weird for an average person, because even if the technology, AI, smart materials (and everything you may consider) exist, it wouldn't change our biology or our way of living.

Think about it: from the point of view of a medieval visitor, **there would always be people eating, sleeping, working, having distractions**, and from these informations, the average visitor would quickly understand from observation how to use a microwave, a waterbed, a computer or a television, even if not understanding the whole technology behind it.

### On the other hand...

If no humans are inhabiting this future, it could really turn *really weird*, considering machines, AI and sentient materials would have nothing to be compared with our own biology. Their needs could be totally out of range of our comprehension, given some robots or AI would only react as they were programmed in the first time.

See how Wall-e spent decades collecting trash? Imagine that Eve never came to Earth (and that Wall-e didn't degrade), he would have continued this for millenias, even after the planet is clean. But yet he would continue collecting stuff and piling them. That would make no sense for an average visitor. This is the kind of surreal moment you're looking for.

### But...

That said, what would AI do without humans? Most machines are or will be programmed to serve us. If your future has no humans, the AI could decide to make all machines stop because they would be no use from anyone.

And if your future has humans, then the AI will promptly try to help your random visitor in every aspect of his life (even if it seems oddly intrusive), because it is programmed for this. Within a few days, he would have adapted and won't find it weird anymore...

Comment: Change our bodies by the use of biotechnology and cyborg upgrades will also part of the technological development.Even reverse the aging process.

Comment: Have you already seen old actors having abused of plastic surgery, to the extent they are now in the uncanny valley? Your future humans may consider _this_ as the new norm of beauty, when your "average person" would only see uglyness everywhere. Creepy effects may kick in when the inhabitants of the future want to force him to get into the norm.